# What is the most appropriate way to calculate the mean value of x_data and 1,000 control samples and the corresponding error for a fair comparison?

Tags: numpy, statistics

I have 5,000 x_data samples and corresponding 1000 control samples for each. So, control samples is composed of 5000 * 1000 2D arrays.

In this case, when drawing a histogram according to a specific bin for x_data, I want to compare x_data and control datain each bin. I have 3 questions about this.

1. **What would be the most appropriate way to calculate the mean value of x_data and control data and the corresponding error for a fair comparison?** (Standard error was used in the example, but I'm not sure it is correct way and what is the best way to calculate error)
2. If we get the error value of each control sample, **how should I combine error of 1000 control samples for comparison with x_data to be statistically valid?** (In the example, the error of 1000 standard errors was calculated as Error propagation for average operation.)
3. I am curious about the statistical reason for having to calculate like this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### x data & Control data
x_data = np.random.normal(5, 10, 5000)
con_data = np.random.normal(5, 10, 5000 * 1000).reshape(5000, 1000)

### Digitize
bins = np.linspace(-30, 30, 9)
digit = np.digitize(x_data, bins=bins)

x_ticks = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) / 2

### Array for mean & std
x_data_mean = np.zeros_like(x_ticks)
x_data_error = np.zeros_like(x_ticks)

con_data_mean = np.zeros_like(x_ticks)
con_data_error = np.zeros_like(x_ticks)

for i in range(np.min(digit), np.max(digit)):
    mask = digit == i

    ### x data
    x_data_i = x_data[mask]

    # Calcuate mean & standard error of x data
    x_data_mean[i - 1] = np.mean(x_data_i)
    x_data_error[i - 1] = np.std(x_data_i) / np.sqrt(len(x_data_i))

    ### Control data
    con_data_i = con_data[mask].T
    con_data_mean_i = np.zeros(1000, dtype=float)
    con_data_error_i = np.zeros(1000, dtype=float)

    for j in range(0, 1000):
        con_data_ij = con_data_i[j]

        # Calculate mean & standard error of each control sample
        con_data_mean_i[j] = np.mean(con_data_ij)
        con_data_error_i[j] = np.std(con_data_ij) / np.sqrt(len(con_data_ij))

    # Combine mean & standard error of 1000 control samples
    con_data_mean[i - 1] = np.mean(con_data_mean_i)
    con_data_error[i - 1] = np.sqrt(np.sum(con_data_mean_i ** 2)) / 1000

plt.errorbar(x_ticks, x_data_mean, yerr=x_data_error)
plt.errorbar(x_ticks, con_data_mean, yerr=con_data_error)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

So far, I have tried and considered various error calculations, but I don't know what is the most statistically reasonable. I am asking for help on this.

Thank you & Have a nice day.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for the stats site (cross-validated), since you don't have any concrete problem with the code.